Why not "sind verlassen"?
In my dictionary "verlassen" can mean to leave (something), which to me sounds like a movement. Yet the dictionary is quite unambiguous about that the auxilliary verb to use is "haben". Why is this inconsistency?
When we're on it, the opposite could be asked about "bleiben"

As has been pointed out, transitive verbs always use haben as the auxiliary. This even leads to alternations such as the following, where the auxiliary changes to haben in the transitive use.

er ist in den Graben gefahren
er hat das Auto in den Graben gefahren

Regarding the rule that "movement verbs use sein for the perfect", a relevant test for whether an intransitive verb should be considered a movement verb is whether a directional adverbial can be present. However, er verließ die Wohnung in den Supermarkt is completely impossible. Again, there are alternations such as with humpeln:

nach seiner Verletzung hat er tüchtig gehumpelt
er ist unter Schmerzen (von der Arbeit) nach Hause gehumpelt

The first would be translated into English as walk with a limp, have a limp; it is a manner of moving, but not an act of movement from one place to another. In the second variant, humpeln is used for movement from A to B (he limped home from work), which falls under the "movement rule".
Verbs that, in their most basic meaning, signify movement retain sein even when they do not.

das wäre für mich nicht infrage gekommen

Also note that movement isn't a necessary condition for an intransitive verb to use sein in the perfect. Some change of state verbs have sein as well.

"Opa ist eingeschlafen" kann auch heißen, dass er gestorben ist

Finally, the so-called copula verbs sein, werden, bleiben also have sein in the perfect.

Both are possible, but it's a different meaning as it's a different form of the verb. Logic does not always apply to verb forms, and there surely are no rules without exception. However, if you like consistency, maybe rather think of "to abandon" as a possible translation which rather signifies a change of state rather than an act of movement.
consider these forms:

verlassen --> to leave, to abandon
etwas verlassen haben --> to have left something or some place (behind), to have abandoned something or some place
verlassen sein --> to be left behind or alone, to be abandoned. This is basically a description of the state, the past passive form of the verb; in present form it is "verlassen werden" (being left alone or being abandoned).

Thus:

Ich habe den Hof verlassen --> I (have) left the courtyard / I (have) left the farm (depending on context)
Der Hof ist verlassen --> The courtyard is empty / The farm is abandoned (again: correct translation depends on context)


But "verlassen" is listed as an adjective in its own right (with that meaning). Also it's not the abandoned that is the subject in that case (it's whoever abandoned the abandoned that is the subject). But I guess that "sein" can't be used as auxiliare verb if the participle is used as an adjective with different meaning (other than the perfect).

@skyking: "verlassen" is an adjective, yes, but only because the PPP (past participle) of a verb can be used as such. In fact the word  "verlassen" could be either the infinitive or the past participle, these two forms are homonyms. "verlassen sein" (to be abandoned) is using the past participle as an adjective, like "groß sein" (to be big), "alt sein" (to be old), etc.. "verlassen haben" is using the word as past participle: "ich habe verlassen" (I have left, I abandoned)

For "verlassen", there is very simple reason: transitive verbs never take "sein" for perfect, as this is already the passive. The same holds for "betreten", "durchgehen", "umrennen" etc.
"bleiben" is clearly a verb of motion, as it conveys the lack of motion:) Joking aside, this "motion / not a motion" is really not that easy to explain, and sometimes just remembering it is easier than thinking about why speakers perceive something a certain way.

"Bleiben" as the absence of movement reminds me on a current discussion on Christianity SE about showing omnipotence by not doing something!
